# Объединить 3 таблицы в сложном запросе

Tags: sql

Привет всем. У меня есть три таблицы: `games`, `active\_user_games`, `balance`.

```
games

+------+---------+
|  id  |  title  |
+------+---------+
|  1   | my-game |
+------+---------+
|  2   | the are |
+----------------+

active\_user_game

+------+-----------+--------------+
|  id  |  user_id  |   game_id    | 
+------+-----------+--------------+
|  1   | 1         |     1        |
+------+-----------+--------------+
|  2   | 2         |     1        |
+------------------+--------------+
|  3   | 3         |     2        |
+------+-----------+--------------+
|  4   | 4         |     2        |
+------------------+--------------+

balance

+------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  id  |  user_id  |   item_id    |   summ     |
+------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  1   | 1         |     1        |   1000     |
+------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  2   | 2         |     1        |   1000     |
+------------------+--------------+------------+
|  3   | 3         |     2        |   2000     |
+------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  4   | 4         |     2        |   2000     |
+------------------+--------------+------------+
```

Мне нужно вывести все записи из таблицы games и добавить 2 столбца данных к каждой записи, которые вычисляются по данным из двух остальных таблиц. А именно мне нужно вывести количество участников из таблицы `active\_user_game` к конкретной игре функцией `count()` и сумму платежей этих участников из таблицы `balance` функцией `sum(balance.summ)`.
Я делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT g.id, g.title, au.game_id, au.id, b.id, b.user_id, COUNT(au.game_id) AS users,     SUM(b.summ) AS bank
FROM games AS g
  JOIN active_user_game AS au ON au.game_id = g.id
  JOIN balance AS b ON b.item_id = g.id
WHERE g.private = 0 AND g.closed = 0 AND b.type IN(5,6)
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g.vip DESC, g.benefit DESC
```

Но так как в разных таблицах разное количество записей, он выводит users и bank с неправильными цифрами, помогите решить эту задачу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
SELECT g.id, g.title, 
  au.game_id, au.cnt AS users, 
  b.user_id, b.summ AS bank
FROM games AS g
  LEFT JOIN (select game_id, count(*) as cnt 
        from active_user_game 
        group by game_id) AS au ON au.game_id = g.id
  LEFT JOIN (select item_id, sum(summ) as summ 
        from balance 
        where type IN(5,6) 
        group by item_id) AS b ON b.item_id = g.id
WHERE g.private = 0 AND g.closed = 0
ORDER BY g.vip DESC, g.benefit DESC
```

Кроме того, `au.id` и `b.id` у вас выбирались бы по принципу, известному только mysql (вероятно первое попавшееся значение), поэтому смысла в них нет. А в других субд такой запрос просто не выполнился бы с ошибкой что-то типа "поле au.id, b.id не входят в группу".
Далее, mysql поля в выборке с одинаковыми названиями склеивает в одно поле, поэтому все три id так не получить было все равно, надо было бы пользоваться псевдонимами.

Comment: Да верно, всё работает, не знал, что в джойне можно использовать такую конструкцию, надеюсь, это не слишком ресурсозатратный запрос.)